# Are questions supposed to not include relevant language[s] in the title?

Tags: discussion, edits, title

A recent question of mine was modified to remove `R` (the language in question)  from the title and body of the question. (He also removed a 'thank you', which I'm learning is super-a-ok)

[Suppress one command's output in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723034/suppress-one-commands-output)

I'm concerned removing a language from the title may make this answer *harder* to find in the future. At the very least, in a list of search results (internal to SO or external) the [r] tag is not as readily apparent as... the title of the question.

I figured I'd ask here before trying to revert the title of the post.

Comment: FWIW, the system takes the foremost in the question's tags that doesn't already appear in the title and prepends it to the <title> element for SEO purposes. So for example, you may either see "Howto suppress one command's output in R?" or "r - Suppress one command's output" in a Google SERP.

Comment: This doesn't happen outside of SERPs, though, so good luck to anyone figuring out what "Suppress one command's output" is supposed to be about when looking at your profile.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no need to include the language in the title. The tags can handle that for you.

There is a larger [post on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) about this:

> Stack Overflow has an extensive tag system which allows users to identify what technology is involved in a question, watch or ignore certain subjects, narrow their searches to a specific area, and even learn about the tag's subject via its wiki.
>
> This tag system works. You can rely on it to notify users who are interested in a tag about your question. Stack Overflow is optimized so that tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of the question. Users are guaranteed to view your tags, and will take them into account when answering your question.
>
> **Therefore it is completely unnecessary to force tags into your question titles.**

Comment: The important part though is: Do not **force** tags into question titles. If they are an organic part of it, that's good. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

The language may be included in the title if the expected answer is highly language dependent, and the answer for the different language is totally useless (how to list the directory in Java vs how to list the directory in Bash).

I think that failure to do so provokes the incorrect closing the question as the duplicate (How to list directory in C++? [This question already has an answer here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649347/how-to-list-all-files-in-current-directory)). The question how to list the directory without mentioning the language should be closed as too broad.

As a result, I would suggest to keep the language name in the title at least for questions that have the history of such a requests to close. Of course, we could say that the close-voters should read the tags before voting, but sometimes seems not the case, especially for more rare features that one may assume are specific of one language only (it is about try-catch-finally? [surely Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545230/c-sharp-how-does-the-try-catch-finally-block-work), that else it could be?).

The language tag is also always required.